# Why is it that the graph of mAP not ascending as training steps increases?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I trained my own ssd coco model with 1000 train pictures and 100 test. I was just curious why is the number of training steps is not directly proportional to the mAP or why does it have lower mAP at certain training steps like shown below image?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Neural Network optimizer functions such as gradient descent and it's variations (http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/) attempt to update the weights of your model at each time step in such a way as to get closer to the smallest possible loss. Sometimes it steps in the wrong direction, sometimes it steps in the right directions, but the step is too big so that it steps right past the minimum.

Sophisticated optimizer functions such as Adam seek to minimize this problem by making the steps taken more consistent and also progressively smaller over time.

What you are seeing above is therefore completely normal - i.e. the mAP jumps up and down but over time it increases.